# WebDriverWait.until - javascript error: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I have a function to access a website and export some Excel file. For that, I import from selenium:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

And I call the function ***every_downloads_chrome*** inside the 'until' of ***WebDriverWait***.

```
nameFile = WebDriverWait(driver, 120, 1).until(every_downloads_chrome)

# method to get the downloaded file name
def every_downloads_chrome(driver):
    if not driver.current_url.startswith("chrome://downloads"):
        driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        driver.get("chrome://downloads/")
    return driver.execute_script("""
        var items = downloads.Manager.get().items_;
        if (items.every(e => e.state === "COMPLETE"))
            return items.map(e => e.fileUrl || e.file_url);
        """)
```

This works on my computer, a Windows 10 - Google Chrome version 79.0.3945.130 (64 bits). However, when I try on the 'Production computer', with Windows 10 - Google 80.0.3987.122 (64 bits), I have the error:

```
Erro Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.122)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-1-e86f4018e9d8>", line 394, in job
    nameFile = WebDriverWait(driver, 120, 1).until(every_downloads_chrome)
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "<ipython-input-1-e86f4018e9d8>", line 91, in every_downloads_chrome
    """)
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.122)
```

Comment: I believe .until is expecting a bool.  Looks like you're returning a file path?

Comment: Yes, the function return the file path of the Excel file downloaded.

Comment: don't use the webdriverwait... just call the function.

Comment: I found the problem: I have Selenium tests which use downloads.Manager.get() , which no longer works after version 80: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/28267973?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem: downloads.Manager.get() doesn't work after version 80 of Chrome.

So, I chang# method to get the downloaded file name

```
def every_downloads_chrome(driver):
    if not driver.current_url.startswith("chrome://downloads"):
        driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        driver.get("chrome://downloads/")
    return driver.execute_script("""
        var elements = document
        .querySelector('downloads-manager')
        .shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList').items;
        if (elements.every(e => e.state === "COMPLETE"))
               return elements.map(elements =>elements.fileUrl || elements.file_url);
        """)
```